# php5_invoke xdebug: no action - module was disabled by maintainer for apache2 SAPI

Tags: php, apache2, xdebug, linux-mint

I was using `Linux Mint 16`, I performed the update today to version `Linux Mint 17`, updated everything correctly, but xdebug was not activated, so I uninstalled it and installed it again and I noticed that when I went to install xdebug, it showed this message warning you can not activate.

This is due to some security issue of the extension? How do I enable xdebug now this new updated installation?

```
default@Default-PC ~ $ sudo apt-get install php5-xdebug
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php5-xdebug
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/253 kB of archives.
After this operation, 982 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package php5-xdebug.
(Reading database ... 272442 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../php5-xdebug_2.2.3-2build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php5-xdebug (2.2.3-2build1) ...
Setting up php5-xdebug (2.2.3-2build1) ...
php5_invoke xdebug: no action - module was disabled by maintainer for apache2 SAPI
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to manually activate again, the solution is to create a shortcut xdebug.ini file and paste it in the loading extensions folder.

Create a shortcut `xdebug.ini` file to your desktop:

```
/etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini
```

The contents of this file is:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
```

Copy the shortcut created on the desktop to the folder:

```
/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/
```

[image: xdebug.ini in folder mods-available in php5]
[image: xdebug.ini shortcut like as 20-xdebug.ini (renamed by me)]